# How can Storage Spaces run Parity Space where NumberOfDisks is not a multiple of NumberOfColumns?

Tags: storage-spaces

The question says it all, here comes the sauce:

1. Have a pool of 3x2TB disks.
2. Create Parity-protected Space in that Pool.
3. Windows automatically sets the Virtual Disk's `numberOfColumns` to 3 (the required minimum).
4. Connect 2 more physical disks to the PC.
5. Extend the Pool by adding the 2 new disks to it.
6. Extend the Space accordingly (it's thinly provisioned, so doesn't matter how much you increase it).
7. Observe utilization of disks.

Current state:
[Windows showing current Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czJGG.png)

And to prove the `numberOfColumns`:
[PowerShell showing the column count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce9mT.png)

From the image, it is clear that I currently have 5 disks in a Space that has 3 columns and Windows is telling me to add 2 more disks for a total of 7 disks in a 3-column Space. Why?

And secondly, how can Windows stripe data into a 3-column Space with 5 disks and use the 2 extra disks at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned over time that `numberOfColumns` value doesn't determine number of physical discs, because a virtual disk (a Space in Storage Spaces terminology) is not tied to any specific physical drives. The pool and the virtual disk are two separate layers. The pool doesn't care about what data is being stored into it's physical disks, and virtual disk has no care in the world about how many physical disks there are in the pool. If the parity-enabled virtual disk is operating with 3 columns, it only means that during every write the data is split into 2 stripes, third stripe is calculated as parity from the other two and then 3 disks are grabbed from the pool to write these stripes onto. The virtual disk driver does not care which 3 physical disks they are, as long as they are 3 independent physical disks. `numberOfColumns` then only refers to how many individual physical disks have to be available in order for the virtual disk to make a successful write operation, hence defining the minimum amount of physical disks required. If 5 disks are present in the pool, the pool supplies disks for writing in such a way that ensures balanced utilization for disks in the pool (usage and capacity-wise).

Answer (score 0):

The low capacity warning does not relate to any calculation of columns and
stripes, but simply to the percentage of used space.

From the
[Storage Spaces Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx),
section
[Why do I have a low capacity warning even though I still have unused pool capacity?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx#Why_do_I_have_a_low_capacity_warning_even_though_I_still_have_unused_pool_capacity):

> Storage Spaces provides advance notification of thinly provisioned storage spaces when the storage pool does not have enough capacity spread among a sufficient number of disks to continue to write new data. **The default warning point is 70% capacity utilization**.

Your 5 disks are pretty full. The total capacity utilization is about 72%
for the entire storage space, which causes the warning.

Comment: Thanks. How can Storage Spaces run Parity Space where NumberOfDisks is not a multiple of NumberOfColumns?

Comment: I don't think the two are connected, and I have seen it recommended to use as many columns as disks.

Comment: My question isn't why is Storage Spaces reporting low space, my question is why is it recommending to add 2 disks. If I add 2 disks, I will have 7 drives in a Space that's operating with 3 columns. It makes no sense to me why is it asking for 7 drives for a 3 column Space. Hence the question.

Comment: I think it is only dependent on space utilization. According to my calculations, adding 2 more disks of the same size will reduce utilization to 51%. Close to 50% is perhaps some ideal value that Microsoft prefers. I don't think the columns number is connected to this recommendation. If I'm right your options are: (1) Ignore the warning, (2) Add one more disk to make it go away when utilization drops below 70%.

Comment: What are your calculations then? If the Space is composed of 3 columns, it gives 66 percent efficiency for storage. If I add additional 4 drives for a total of 7 drives in a 3 column Space, the Space can only use 6 of those drives as it has to split every write into 2 rows, and then each row into 2 columns and compute the parity for them (6 chunks total). It can't magically use 7th drive, because it wouldn't be able to maintain 3-drive data separation for anything it writes into it. Am I wrong?

Comment: I believe that these calculations are not part of the reason for the warning. The warning is caused by pure space calculation: `(sum-percents-used) / (disks-number)`.

Comment: I would have been satisfied with that answer, if the message was displayed next to the pool definition. But it is displayed next to the space definition and it makes no sense. It is possible (probable), that I simply don't understand how columns and write distribution works in Storage Spaces, so I've asked [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Server-for-IT-Pro/How-does-Windows-Storage-Spaces-Columns-work/m-p/1053461#M2341) for explanation.

Comment: Understanding that would of course be useful. But for this particular warning: As this is a space warning, it's entirely logical for it to be displayed next to the space definition, so this only strengthens my answer.